# How do I change the color of a button color in plotly for python?

Tags: python, pandas, button, visualization, plotly-python

I am currently working on a histogram with buttons in plotly express. This is my code for the buttons:

```
fig.update_xaxes(
    rangeslider_visible=True,
    rangeselector=dict(
        buttons=list([
            dict(count=6, label="6m", step="month", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(count=1, label="1y", step="year", stepmode="backward"),
            dict(step="all")
        ])
    )
)
```

How can I style the buttons to change the color? Can I do it with these plotly express buttons, or do I have to use another plotly library? The buttons are too bright when I use the plotly dark theme.

The function of the buttons is to change the time series to 1 year, 6 months, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update, this fixed it:

```
fig.update_layout(template='plotly_dark',
                  xaxis_rangeselector_font_color='black',
                  xaxis_rangeselector_activecolor='red',
                  xaxis_rangeselector_bgcolor='green',
                 )
```